# How do I resolve the "This domain has already been signed up for Google Apps" error?

Tags: google-workspace

I want to sign up for Google Apps for Education, but I get this error message:

```
This domain has already been signed up for a Google Apps ...
```

I cancelled my subscription for Google Apps for *Work* on July 28, 2015, and  now I can't sign the same domain up for Google Apps for Education.

What to do?

Comment: Ummm, contact Google?

Comment: sorry, I dont know how to contact google

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to contact Google concerning this issue, there isn't anything anyone outside of Google would be able to help with.

Google Apps for Education, even though it is a forked version of Apps for Work requires a bit more hand holding from Google.

https://support.google.com/a/troubleshooter/2784892?hl=en#ts=2784911

Where you would be directed to fill out this form: 
https://support.google.com/a/contact/admin_no_access